# linux kill process using timeout in milliseconds

Tags: linux, shell, timeout, kill, terminate

I want to force terminate a program after a specified time is elapsed on linux.
I found that 'timeout' util in linux can kill a program after a specified time,
but it does not accept MILLISECONDS.
That is, "timeout TIME ./PROGRAM" kills PROGRAM after TIME elapsed where TIME is not milliseconds but seconds.
Is there a way to kill a process after some MILLISECONDS on linux **SHELL**?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#execute command in background
<command> & 

#get process ID
PROC=$! 

#sleep for 10 milliseconds then kill command
(usleep 10000; kill $PROC) & 

#bring back the process ID, finish command or kill it
fg $PROC
```

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of timeout actually supports milliseconds as well. You can supply the waiting time as a floating point number. For example

```
$timeout 0.003s sleep 0.003 && echo foo
$
```

while

```
$ timeout 0.003s sleep 0.001 && echo foo
foo
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function, accept millisecond values

```
timeout_m ()
{
  $2 &
  for (( y=0; y<$1*50; y++ ))
  do
    :
  done
  kill $!
}
```

Comment: and just input different values to figure out what is close to the millsecond sleep required? ;-) ? Changing 50 as needed depending on how fast the hardware is? Good luck to all.