# Preventing "Terminated" message when killing subprocess

Tags: bash, timeout

I am looking for a tool like Linux's "timeout" command that will allow timouet values of less than 1 second. I am using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422740/linux-kill-process-using-timeout-in-milliseconds), but I am running into one problem.

The problem is that sometimes it prints this message, and I am trying to figure out why.

```
./tools/utimeout.sh: line 17: 12369 Terminated              $(./tools/usleep $TIMEOUT ; kill $PROC &> /dev/null)
```

I tried modifying the solution so that the subprocess would be killed before the script exits, but this didn't help.

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=400000

#execute command in background
"$@" &

#get process ID
PROC=$! 

#sleep for 10 milliseconds then kill command
(./tools/usleep $TIMEOUT ; kill $PROC &> /dev/null) & 

CPROC=$!
wait $PROC &> /dev/null
kill $CPROC &> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    # echo "Process timed out."
    exit 1
else
    # echo "Process completed successfully."
    exit 0
fi
```

Since I want to capture stderr from this script, as workaround, I am just removing the message from the error logs with sed. Since this is a hack, I was hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: Use `"$@" &` instead, or your script will not be able to handle arguments containing whitespace and pattern special characters.

Comment: Also, don't use a command substitution for the timer process; just use subshell: `(./tools... ) &`.

Comment: my `timeout` command accepts floating point seconds less than 1. (fedora 21).

Comment: You are correct. (facepalm)

I think what might have confused me is that in Ubuntu, there doesn't seem to be a "usleep" command. Maybe I got confused and got that mixed up in my mind with thinking that there wasn't a timeout command that allow times less than a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the message you can disown the process

```
(./tools/usleep $TIMEOUT ; kill $PROC &> /dev/null) &
disown %
```

and then you cannot wait on it, or you can put it in a subshell:

```
( (./tools/usleep $TIMEOUT ; kill $PROC &> /dev/null) & )
```

but of course then you cannot kill it as $! wont be right.

---

My fedora 21 timeout takes floating point durations:

```
$ time timeout .1 sleep 1
real    0m0.103s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: what is % after 'disown'?

Comment: `disown` takes a list of *jobspecs* saying which jobs to apply it to. A `%` starts each jobspec, and on its own just means the current job (last put in the background). It isn't actually needed here, because `disown` with no arguments applies by default to the current job as well. Search for jobspec in `man bash`.